# Show changes since buffer was opened

Tags: vimdiff, undo-redo

Is it possible to show all changes made to a buffer since the buffer was opened?

This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749297/can-i-see-changes-before-i-save-my-file-in-vim is related, but asks for changes since the last write, which can easily be accomplished by looking at the file on the file system.

I am using persistent undo (`set undofile`), so I cannot use `:earlier <reallylargenumber>`.

Comment: Why can't you use undo? Are you saying you haven't configured it to save enough entries? Then add more! :) I mean, that's Vim's change history mechanism after all.

Comment: :h DiffOrig provides a useful command for this

Comment: @BLayer I don't know how far to go in the undo tree.

Comment: I guess you have to store highest undo sequence number from a autocmd on BufRead/BufReadPost using the function `undotree()`. Than you might be able to determine the value of for `:earlier`.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Contrary to what the help text says this seems to diff to the last saved state (when I change a file then save with `:w`, and then run the command, it shows no change)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played around. Could you try the following (rarely tested):

```
autocmd BufReadPost * let b:undo_seq_load=changenr()

function! DiffSinceLoad()
    let tmpa = tempname()
    let tmpb = tempname()
    let curchange=changenr()
    exe "undo " . b:undo_seq_load
    exec 'w '.tmpa
    exe "undo " . curchange
    exec 'w '.tmpb
    update
    exec 'tabnew '.tmpa
    diffthis
    vert split
    exec 'edit '.tmpb
    diffthis
endfunction
command! -nargs=0 DiffSinceLoad call DiffSinceLoad()
```

This is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/749338/7369280).

Second iteration: This is now in my vimrc.

- Use only one temporary file
- If the buffer with the temporary file gets hidden, it is deleted.
- When the buffer with the temporary file is deleted, `:diffoff` is called via autocmd.

```
" store the changenr at file load
autocmd BufReadPost * let b:changenr_on_load=changenr()
function! DiffSinceLoad()
    let tmpa = tempname()
    let curchange=changenr()
    exe "undo " . b:changenr_on_load
    exe 'w ' . tmpa
    exe 'undo ' . curchange
    "diffthis
    exe 'vertical diffsplit ' . tmpa
    " when buffer gets hidden, delete it and reset diff settings
    setlocal bufhidden=delete
    autocmd BufDelete <buffer> diffoff
    " return to edited file
    wincmd p
endfunction
command! -nargs=0 DiffSinceLoad silent call DiffSinceLoad()
```

Comment: I'm glad you understood what I needed. I'm currently wildly modifying my vimrc and sometimes just don't trust anything that was going on in my sessions.

Comment: @Bananach Great if I could help. If you find problems with this script (as said I didn't really test it), report here so we could improve the answer.

Comment: Is there a need for two  temp files? If one side of the diff is the current state of the buffer in question I'd think you can just `:split` it (or `:vert` or whatever) and call `:diffthis` from the split window.

Comment: @BLayer See update.

Comment: Cool. Just FYI, you could combine the `vsplit` and two `diffthis` calls into a single command: `exec "vert diffsplit ".tmpa`.

Answer (score -1):

This will do what you're looking for:

```
:w !diff % -
```

Comment: This shows the diffs since the last write, but not since loading the file.